# Как поменять расширение с .db на .bytes в базе данных SQlite?

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3, расширения

я создал базу на DB browser for SQlite, сохранил и в папке отобразилось что он с расширением .db, а мне нужно .bytes.
Я попробовал просто по-другому сохранить т.е. написал name.bytes, но все равно пишет что расширение .db.
Возможно я не так что-то делаю, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно поменять расширение ?

Comment: После сохранения переименуй

Comment: @eri, спасибо получилось